# Discord Py can't figure out how to add roles

Tags: python, roles, discord

I've looked everywhere and people just tell me to use the documentation and that doesn't help, I've already got on_message(message) defined so I can't use a member parameter and I want people to be set to a certain role when they say a keyword
here's what I got but it doesn't work:

```
if message.content.lower() == "!changeadmin"
role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Administrator")
await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

I always get returned with

```
    Ignoring exception in on_message
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
   packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
        yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\josep\OneDrive\Documents\New folder\New folder\mybot1.py", 
    line 58, in on_message
        role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="admin")
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

EDIT:
This is my full code (excluding the token at the bottom):

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
import random
import ctx

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

chat_filter = ["CUNT", "NIGGER", "NIGGA", "FUCK", "BITCH", "DICK", "WANKER"]
bypass_list = ["227007454775476224"]
possible_responses =  [
            'That is a resounding no',
            'It is not looking likely',
            'Too hard to tell',
            'It is quit possible',
            'Definitely',
        ]
server = '242547220765868033'
roles = ['442351132615114772']

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online and connected to Discord")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description='A bot that greets the user back.')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    contents = message.content.split(" ") #contents is a list type
    for word in contents:
        if word.upper() in chat_filter:
            if not message.author.id in bypass_list:
                try:
                    await client.delete_message(message)
                    await client.send_message(channel.message, "**Hey!** You're not allowed to use that word here!")
                except discord.errors.NotFound:
                    return    
    if message.content.upper().startswith('!PING'):
        userID = message.author.id
        await client.send_message((discord.Object(id='442333293539622913')), "<@%s> Pong!" % (userID))
    if message.content.upper().startswith('!SAY'):
        if message.author.id == "227007454775476224" or message.author.id == "399959323591180288":
            args = message.content.split(" ")
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "%s" % (" ".join(args[1:])))
        else:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "Sorry only the bot owner has permission to use this command")
    if message.content.lower() == "cookie":
        await client.send_message(message.channel, ":cookie:") #responds with Cookie emoji when someone says "cookie"
    if message.content.lower() == "!website":
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "habbo.com")

    if message.content.upper().startswith('!EIGHTBALL'):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, random.choice(possible_responses))
    if message.content.lower() == '!changeadmin':
        role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="admin")
        await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

Comment: `message.server` not `server`, your `server` is just a string id.

Comment: thanks I'll try this
EDIT: I tried that and I just get in return:
`Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\josep\OneDrive\Documents\New folder\New folder\mybot1.py", line 59, in on_message
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
NameError: name 'member' is not defined` @abccd

Comment: That's when I try to execute it on discord, I've changed the server.roles to message.server.roles and now it's the next line where I get an error

Comment: `message.author` not `member`, you don't have a `member` in your code.

Comment: @abccd sorry to keep coming back to you but I changed member to message.author and I still got an error saying:

'`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id` on line 59 which is `await client.add_roles(message.author, role)`
EDIT: Fixed, thanks for your help, I changed the name="admin" to id="[id]"

Answer (score 0):

sorry if this a late reply :)
so if u wanna add roles to members try this code:

```
    @client.command()
     @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def giverole(ctx,member :discord.Member,role):
        try:
            add_role= discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role)
            await member.add_roles(add_role)      
            await ctx.send('Updated')
        except:
            await ctx.send("role not found!")
```

so the code gonna work like this: let's say prefix= "?"

?giverole @member example

the bot gonna search a role name  "example" from guild role and give it to @member